# SQL Server collect newest transactions and ignore transactions that have already been selected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Every now and then I'm presented with a scenario that at first seems simple and straight forward, but upon further review has complexity that is beyond me.

I have anvils and anvil_ledger transactions. I'm trying to create a batch process that scoops the latest anvil transactions for a daily report.

Now an anvil might have two ledger transactions and I want to get the latest one.

Here is the data and code...

```
drop table #anvil
drop table #anvil_ledger
drop table #anvil_batch

create  table #anvil(anvil_guid uniqueidentifier constraint anvil_guid_pk  primary key nonclustered
, anvil_status varchar(10)
, balance money
, utcinserted datetime constraint anvil_utcinserted_df default getutcdate()
)

create table #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid uniqueidentifier not null, post_date datetime not null, anvil_guid uniqueidentifier, action varchar(10) not null, amount money, utcinserted datetime constraint anvil_ledger_utcinserted_df default getutcdate())
alter table #anvil_ledger add constraint anvil_ledger_anvil_ledger_guid_post_date_df primary key (anvil_ledger_guid, post_date)

create table #anvil_batch(anvil_batch_guid uniqueidentifier, anvil_batch_date datetime,  anvil_guid uniqueidentifier, anvil_ledger_guid uniqueidentifier, post_date datetime, action varchar(10), utcinserted datetime constraint anvil_batch_guid_utcinserted_df default getutcdate())

insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('3791A9C1-8697-4E12-8B0C-1D970ED90729',  1.00, 'Open')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('A8AFCDD9-FD10-4443-B6AF-7FB30A260E29',  2.00, 'Open')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('03C8B5AD-75E3-4BF4-B0CE-292FC2993F9C',  3.00, 'Open')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('B280904E-D454-4343-911B-FEA85DEE478E',  4.00, 'Open')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('5DAEFAAB-8432-4AA6-A616-FC4962279829',  0.00, 'Closed')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('750EDD08-C76E-4AE5-A489-1035F889D576',  0.00, 'Closed')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('051D7A55-CCAB-4F20-82F7-799C1710CC2B',  7.00, 'Open')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('46E97CA7-8DBB-4D13-B123-614E180EF3AD',  8.00, 'Open')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('6EC2DCBF-A6ED-450E-9398-F86BC6DD3786',  9.00, 'Open')
insert into #anvil(anvil_guid, balance, anvil_status) values('12C8F5AA-31B9-4E5C-981A-4C246BF86DA1', 10.00, 'Open')


insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('55287267-40DD-48BC-A4F5-F2F8E9344813', '2021-02-26 01:00:00.000', '3791A9C1-8697-4E12-8B0C-1D970ED90729', 'New', 1.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('7C56E350-EAD8-468C-82AF-05A858686776', '2021-02-26 01:00:00.000', 'A8AFCDD9-FD10-4443-B6AF-7FB30A260E29', 'New',  2.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('D17081C7-E965-4C8D-9275-1982B301FE45', '2021-02-26 02:00:00.000', '03C8B5AD-75E3-4BF4-B0CE-292FC2993F9C', 'New', 3.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('F9EF78FA-6517-49FA-98FF-0D2739D5026D', '2021-02-26 03:00:00.000', 'B280904E-D454-4343-911B-FEA85DEE478E', 'New', 4.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('848D6796-FE7D-4908-A0F4-8B14A0FA4DE2', '2021-02-26 04:00:00.000', '5DAEFAAB-8432-4AA6-A616-FC4962279829', 'New', 5.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('D0C79E19-F7A1-4CF9-BDC8-821EAD390586', '2021-02-26 05:00:00.000', '750EDD08-C76E-4AE5-A489-1035F889D576', 'New', 6.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('30AF2C73-0418-4D65-BE62-C2992CC50DE2', '2021-02-26 06:00:00.000', '051D7A55-CCAB-4F20-82F7-799C1710CC2B', 'New', 7.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('AA9996D8-1073-4660-97E4-C8AB92E31667', '2021-02-26 07:00:00.000', '46E97CA7-8DBB-4D13-B123-614E180EF3AD', 'New', 8.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('E9065F4E-8D92-4111-AAD5-800CB0B723B0', '2021-02-26 08:00:00.000', '6EC2DCBF-A6ED-450E-9398-F86BC6DD3786', 'New', 9.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('F2A9D713-B38C-4068-9AC7-68B872FFD8AA', '2021-02-26 09:00:00.000', '12C8F5AA-31B9-4E5C-981A-4C246BF86DA1', 'New', 10.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('FA81B21E-B116-4F51-984B-59C7A5B3AC0C', '2021-02-27 04:00:00.000', '5DAEFAAB-8432-4AA6-A616-FC4962279829', 'Cancel', -5.00)
insert into #anvil_ledger(anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, anvil_guid, action, amount) values('655ACAD0-B4B7-4E6F-BCF1-C19DE415908E', '2021-02-27 05:00:00.000', '750EDD08-C76E-4AE5-A489-1035F889D576', 'Cancel', -6.00)


declare @anvil_batch_guid uniqueidentifier = 'ABE64AC0-7448-4A03-9A0D-E5D67C9585DC'
, @anvil_batch_date datetime = '2021-02-27 10:00:00.000'


insert into #anvil_batch(anvil_batch_guid, anvil_batch_date, anvil_guid, anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, action)
select @anvil_batch_guid, @anvil_batch_date, vt.anvil_guid, vt.anvil_ledger_guid, vt.post_date, vt.action
from(
select al.post_date, al.anvil_ledger_guid, al.anvil_guid, al.action, al.amount, a.balance, a.anvil_status, row_number() over(partition by a.anvil_guid order by al.post_date desc) as rn
from #anvil_ledger al 
inner join #anvil a on a.anvil_guid = al.anvil_guid
) vt
where rn = 1
```

So far this works. I'm able to get the latest anvil_ledger transaction. The records are inserted into #anvil_batch.

Now here is were it gets tricky. I want to run this every day and of course I don't want to included anvil_ledger transactions that have already been collected. My initial thought is to left join to anvil_batch and and filter records that are not null...

```
select  vt.anvil_guid, vt.anvil_ledger_guid, vt.post_date, vt.balance, vt.action
from(
select al.post_date, al.anvil_ledger_guid, al.anvil_guid, al.action, al.amount, a.balance, a.anvil_status, row_number() over(partition by a.anvil_guid order by al.post_date desc) as rn
from #anvil_ledger al 
inner join #anvil a on a.anvil_guid = al.anvil_guid
left join #anvil_batch ab on ab.post_date = al.post_date and ab.anvil_guid = al.anvil_guid
where ab.anvil_guid is null
) vt
where rn = 1
```

This returns two records that I don't want...

```
anvil_guid                           anvil_ledger_guid                    post_date               balance               action
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----------------------- --------------------- ----------
750EDD08-C76E-4AE5-A489-1035F889D576 D0C79E19-F7A1-4CF9-BDC8-821EAD390586 2021-02-26 05:00:00.000 0.00                  New
5DAEFAAB-8432-4AA6-A616-FC4962279829 848D6796-FE7D-4908-A0F4-8B14A0FA4DE2 2021-02-26 04:00:00.000 0.00                  New
```

I want this query to return no records because I already have the latest record in anvil_batch.

Now if a newer anvil_ledger transaction is inserted then I would want that newer transaction to be selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is to merge the new data in. For this we can use [the `MERGE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```sql
WITH Source AS (
    select vt.anvil_guid, vt.anvil_ledger_guid, vt.post_date, vt.action, al.amount, a.balance, a.anvil_status
    from(
        select al.anvil_guid, al.anvil_ledger_guid, al.post_date, al.action, al.amount, a.balance, a.anvil_status,
            row_number() over (partition by a.anvil_guid order by al.post_date desc) as rn
        from #anvil_ledger al 
        inner join #anvil a on a.anvil_guid = al.anvil_guid
    ) vt
    where rn = 1
)

MERGE #anvil_batch t  -- WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)   -- advised if you are worried about concurrency
USING Source s
ON t.anvil_guid = s.anvil_guid

WHEN MATCHED AND t.anvil_ledger_guid <> s.anvil_ledger_guid THEN
UPDATE SET
    anvil_batch_guid = @anvil_batch_guid,
    anvil_batch_date = @anvil_batch_date,
    anvil_guid = s.anvil_guid,
    anvil_ledger_guid = s.anvil_ledger_guid,
    post_date = s.post_date,
    action = s.action,
    amount = s.amount,
    balance = s.balance,
    anvil_status = s.anvil_status

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
INSERT
    (anvil_batch_guid, anvil_batch_date, anvil_guid, anvil_ledger_guid, post_date, action, amount, balance, anvil_status)
    VALUES (@anvil_batch_guid, @anvil_batch_date, s.anvil_guid, s.anvil_ledger_guid, s.post_date, s.action, s.amount, s.balance, s.anvil_status);
```

I am unsure what you want to do with the `anvil_batch_guid` and `anvil_batch_date` columns, if there is a match.

---

See [The MERGE Statement in SQL Server 2008](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/) on SImpleTalk for a fuller explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your window function is in the wrong place.  I would suggest:

```
select al.*
from (select al.*,
             row_number() over (partition by al.anvil_guid order by al.post_date desc) as seqnum
      from #anvil_ledger al 
     ) al left join
     #anvil_batch ab
     on ab.post_date = al.post_date and ab.anvil_guid = al.anvil_guid
where seqnum = 1 and ab.anvil_guid is null;
```

I left out the `#anvil` part because I think it just confuses the important part of the logic (you can of course include it).

Your query fails because it is doing the left join and filtering *before* calculating the row number.